# What operand-size should RET default to?

Tags: assembly, x86, 64-bit, nasm, x86-64

My question concerns **RET**urn instructions in **64bit mode** and their operand-size, which specifies how much information is popped from stack to RIP and how many bytes is RSP incremented by.

I noticed that some assemblers leave Intel-defined default operand size. i.e. 64 bits for near return and 32 bits for far return:

```
 1          ; Assembled with NASM 2.12 command "nasm TestRET.asm -l TestRET.lst"
 2                     BITS 64
 3 00000000 66CF       IRETW ; Opsize 16.
 4 00000002 CF         IRETD ; Opsize 32.
 5 00000003 48CF       IRETQ ; Opsize 64.
 6 00000005 66CF   o16 IRET  ; Opsize 16.
 7 00000007 CF     o32 IRET  ; Opsize 32.
 8 00000008 48CF   o64 IRET  ; Opsize 64.
 9 0000000A CF         IRET  ; Opsize 32, default.
10                 
11 0000000B 66CB   o16 RETF  ; Opsize 16.
12 0000000D CB     o32 RETF  ; Opsize 32.
13 0000000E 48CB   o64 RETF  ; Opsize 64.
14 00000010 CB         RETF  ; Opsize 32, default.
15                 
16 00000011 66C3   o16 RETN  ; Opsize 16.
17 00000013 C3     o32 RETN  ; Opsize 32 should not be available, NASM error?
18 00000014 48C3   o64 RETN  ; Opsize 64, REX.W ignored as RETN is promoted to 64 bits.
19 00000016 C3         RETN  ; Opsize 64, default.
```

I am not experienced in writing call-gates and task-gates but I think that the default operand size should correspond with segment size, which is 64 in case of 64bit mode.

**What operand-size do programmers expect from an assembler in 64bit mode when they use IRET, RETF, RETN without further specification?**

Comment: Who knows? I doubt any one has done a survey. What's your real question?

Comment: @RossRidge Should my program translate RETF as CB or 48CB ?

Comment: Your program is an assembler? I don't think its going to matter much, there really isn't any reason to code a far return in 64-bit code. Also RETF isn't officially an instruction so if you document it you can do whatever you want.

Comment: @RossRidge Yes, one reason which occurred me is coding an interrupt handler, call gate etc. 
Mnemonic RETF is officially documented in AMD Programmer's Manual Volume 3 on page 280. http://support.amd.com/TechDocs/24594.pdf

Comment: Intel just uses RET for both near and far returns. No one codes call gates, etc... and interrupt handlers use IRET.

Comment: I'm sure I'm out of my depth here, but wouldn't the question be "What operand-size do **compilers** expect from an assembler..."  Possibly also interpreters and run-times.  I don't think modern programmers think much at all about function call stack management, even C programmers might only give it a passing nod to make sure the right convention is chosen.

Answer (score 2):

The assumption is that writing `ret` in an asm source file will assemble to a single-byte instruction.

IDK why anyone would use `retf` in 64bit code, so I have no opinion on that.

---

On more careful reading of your table, I see what you're saying about NASM's operand-size overrides.  It doesn't special-case the `o32` / `o64` modifiers for instructions like `RETN`, leading to bogus behaviour like `o64 retn` producing a REX.W=1 prefix (`48 C3`).

I think we should understand NASM's `o32` prefix as meaning "operand-size prefix in 16bit code, otherwise nothing", regardless of the instruction it's applied to, and never implies a REX.W=0 (because that doesn't work anyway for `push`/`pop`).

And similarly, `o64` really means apply REX.W=1, regardless of what instruction it's on.  i.e. it won't omit it on an insn like `push` or `pop` either, will it?

---

---

The ISA is designed so that single-byte `ret` instructions "work".  You don't need a REX prefix on a normal `ret`.  As documented in [the instruction set manual's `ret` entry](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/RET.html):

> In 64-bit mode, the default operation size of this instruction is the stack-address size, i.e. 64 bits. This applies to near returns, not far returns; the default operation size of far returns is 32 bits.

This is similar to how `push`/`pop` defaults to a 64bit operand-size in long mode.  (And, contrary to the implication in the manual, `REX.W=0` can't encode a 32bit push/pop).

AMD generally tried to keep decoding simple.  e.g. `movsxd r64, r/m32` requires a REX prefix (or else it just runs as a potentially-less-efficient `mov`), but for very common instructions like push/pop and ret they saved code-size with design-choices like this.

Comment: Scenarios for a16 retf and a32 retf - you are attempting to return to 16 or 32 bit code. a64 retf, that's a tough one but hypothetically if you had just reloaded the GDT with LGDT and the code segment descriptors in the tables were not the same, you'd want to force CS to reload. In that case a64 retf would make sense.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Tnx, another example requiring `o64 IRET (48CF)` could be the return from an interrupt handler triggered from code loaded above 4GB.
BTW shouldn't read `o64,o32,o16` rather than `a64,a32,a16`? AFAIK a64 (address-size prefix 67) has no meaning on RSP-based instructions in 64bit mode, as documented in POP. Stack pointer size is fixed at 64 bits here.

Comment: Yes @vitsoft all should have been `o` not `a`. Was the last comment I made last night and didn't even notice the typo.